# I have to take rdp session into two different servers in succession before I can take rdp to the PKI server - Automate this?

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell, rdp, pki

Is it possible to write a powershell script that executes on my laptop and copy data from pki server back to my laptop.?
If yes How would one proceed to do so? Right now all this is done manually. What kind of permissions would I need. I have all the passwords for rdp. could the credentials be passed on the successive machine and execute rdp connections? Please help :) Can you guys provide some resources.

[image: connections diagram]

Comment: Talk to your IT department to make it easier. If these hops are fore security reason, there will be no good trying to circumvent them.

Comment: I already have access/credentials to accounts on these servers...can powershell do the rdp on my behalf.

Comment: I don't think you quite got Gerald's comment.

Comment: can you please explain in detail....i am not circumventing them....I just want to automate the process that I already do manually

Comment: There are basically two reasons why you have to go through these hops. Reason 1: the environment just grew that way and nobody really thought about it. Reason 2: These hops are necessary as a security precaution and have been set up deliberately to prevent attacks on a highly sensitive system (which PKI definitely is). In that case you would circumvent security measures that have been put in place deliberately, which in the worst case could result in disciplinary action against you. Talk to your IT department, argue that this makes your work harder and work with them towards a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell could launch the RDP client (mstsc.exe) and begin the first session with saved credentials but it could not do the same thing on the next computer.

If you are able to use PowerShell Remoting instead of RDP, you could do a double or triple hop file copy from the server all via PowerShell.

Comment: I suspect the [double hop limitation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7) may come into play here.

Comment: Agreed @Davidw it's probably easier to do the task manually unless it's frequent :D

Comment: Thanks for the advice....